# mysqli_query without link parameter

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to use mysqli_query without first parameter. Is it possible? if yes then what should be my code without database link

```
<?php
$cnn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$db = mysqli_select_db($cnn, "thedb");
mysqli_query($cnn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($cnn, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 
?>
```

Comment: You want to query without the connection?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You could make your own function, or use the non procedural approach. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php Also only tag languages/drivers being used, PDO has no relation to your query.

Comment: i have to modify my old mysql_query code, But i can not modify that code due to first parameter. That is why i don't want to use first parameter

Comment: You're going to have to change `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query` anyway so I don't see how you expect it to work with no coding changes. You could make it OOP and replace the `mysql_query` with the object and function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with this code

```
public $_link;
function connectHost($host, $user, $password)
{
    $this->_link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);
    if(!$this->_link)
    {
        die("Could not connect to host :(");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public function connectDatabase($database)
{
    $db = mysqli_select_db($this->_link, $database);
    if(!$db)
    {
        die("Could not connect to database :(");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
                mysqli_query($this->_link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            mysqli_query($this->_link, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 
        return true;
    }
}

function execQuery($query)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($this->_link, $query);
    if(!$result)
    {
         //die("Could not execute the query :(");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a connection to be able to execute the query, otherwise, where would it execute?

To better understand this perhaps look at: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Pretty much, I don't see any other way op could do what they wanted and their question made it seem like they weren't sure on what they were doing, so this is the best answer I could think of giving.

Comment: If i go with OOPs style then i have to make lots of changes into my previous code or write a new one. I want to go with procedural style, but i want to find a way to bypass or option first parameter of `mysqli_query` is not there any way to do that. If there is no option then i will have to write whole code again that is the last option i have into my hands